# OpenCV mat not working in debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to create a function making possible the setting of the contrast/brightness of a QImage with OpenCV 3.1. This perfectly works in release but not in debug (it returns a blank image) :

```
QImage getNewImage(QImage *img, float contrast, float brightness)
{
    // Convert image to temporary cv::Mat with a deep copy
    // Output format is BGRA
    cv::Mat temp(img->height(),img->width(),CV_8UC4,(uchar*)img->bits(),img->bytesPerLine());

    temp.convertTo(temp, -1, contrast, brightness);
    cv::cvtColor(temp, temp, CV_BGRA2RGB);

    // Convert back to QImage RGB
    QImage dest((const uchar *) temp.data, temp.cols, temp.rows, temp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    return dest;
}
```

Do you see what could be the problem ?

---

**EDIT**

My .pro (the two related dll are in the bin dir).

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../lib/opencv/include

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += ../lib/opencv/opencv_world310d.lib
} else {
    LIBS += ../lib/opencv/opencv_world310.lib
}
```

Includes :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

Comment: Did you add all libraries in the project settings?

Comment: How do you build this? Can you share your qmake/cmake file in here? maybe something with the optimizations.. ?

Comment: _"// Convert image to temporary cv::Mat with a deep copy"_ that's not a deep copy, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-5) used:

```
QImage dest((const uchar *) temp.data, temp.cols, temp.rows, temp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

> Constructs an image with the given width, height and format, that uses
>   an existing memory buffer, data. The width and height must be
>   specified in pixels. bytesPerLine specifies the number of bytes per
>   line (stride).
>
> The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage and all
>   copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the
>   original buffer.

Make sure to call non-const [QImage::bits()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#bits) before returning from this function:

> Returns a pointer to the first pixel data. This is equivalent to
>   scanLine(0).
>
> Note that QImage uses implicit data sharing. This function performs a
>   deep copy of the shared pixel data, thus ensuring that this QImage is
>   the only one using the current return value.

```
dest.bits(); // does deep copy
return dest;
```

Or you have an internal buffer of `QImage` in an on-stack `Cv::Mat` container which is of course out of scope after returning from `getNewImage` function and you return new `QImage` instance made a shallow copy of `QImage dest`. That is a feature of `QImage` aimed to optimize passing big chunks of graphic data through its instances while no transformation happened, so we cannot avoid calling `QImage::bits` here.

Apparently due run-time differences/between release and debug mode the buffer in a freed stack memory was overridden and that shows the code had a problem. And debug mode run-time does write to freed run-time memory to prevent bugs like this: [In Visual Studio C++, what are the memory allocation representations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, as if I created the Mat object in a function than the qtcreator debugger can not debug that function just stopped with an empty debug window and timed out after a while, so I added the Mat object variable in the class definition and after that the debugger went smoothly and worked as expected! :) (sorry for bad english)